# Convert a animation that is based on a curve modifier to a modifier-free animation

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, export

Alright, describing this with my poor english will be a challange!

I have some objects wrapped around a bezier circle. It looks like the chain of a tracked vehicle. Using a single bone and the curve modifier, I can let the objects move around the bezier circle. Now I want to export the whole scene, including the animation, to a .fbx-file (used in Unreal Engine 4 later).

However, the curve-modifier does not work (I guess it is not even written into the fbx-file, is it?). If I just apply it to the object, it will move the whole object instead of letting the objects rotate around the bezier circle.

Now is there a way to convert the animation (meshes moving around a circle) into a modifier-free version?

Here is a video of my problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgoBHhpgoCQ

Here is the link to my project:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4cbvO9kNaOQUEZOdzhmTjN5bzQ

Looking forward ideas! :-)

Comment: I did it this way for tank tracks but it's not a one click solution by a long shot!  It works well in Vers. 2,77a.  How it will go when exported is an unknown.  The plates are animated around the curve no problems and only for 5 frames.  These are repeated or looped as long as required.  The problem you might have is only one of the 5 models is visible at any single frame. The others are switched to invisible by using the 'eye' icon for each model in the Outliner at right. The Blend file - https://www.dropbox.com/s/35dtvgka986cpco/TankTracksWorkaround.zip?dl=0